# Plesk and node-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, server, plesk

I tried to deploy my node server to my global host on my own server using PLESK control panel. The problem is when I stop my node server OR edit some codes in files.

Test here: http://www.test.mazadona.com:3001/items

Now my server id disabled but still working, also when I edit codes, I'm get same result every time without change that I edited on my files.

Is there any body can help me with that?

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: The node server is still working when I disable it.

Comment: How do you start the app? What is Plesk version and OS installed. What is node.js version you have set to run the application?

Comment: There is no problems with running. I just cannot stop the node server and cannot change codes.

Comment: If I want to do that I have to restart my VPN server.